# Phone Gap in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I m developing a Phone Gap App.
With Java Adt Android my app work!
But when I import the project in Visual Studio 2013,the app not work!
Why?
The code is the same.
I don't change anything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parsing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prova.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body >
    <p>See me</p>

    <script>
        var myArray = ["SAT100000002572"];
        for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {

            var StSimulata = myArray[j];

            url = "http://sat3.altervista.org/index.php?valore=" + StSimulata,

             data = { get_param: 'value' };

            $.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    var StNumber = data[i]["Nr SAT"];

                    $('body').append($('<p>').html('Numero Sat: <a href ="http://sat3.altervista.org/DettaglioSat.html?id=' + StNumber + '">' + data[i]["Nr SAT"] + '</a>'));

                    $('body').append($('<p>').html('Data Apertura: ' + data[i]["Data Apertura"]));
                }

            });

        }
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android PhoneGap Application can be used in Visual Stdio,

**Refer this Link:**

http://blog.geekypedia.net/archive/2013/10/08/android-app-development-in-html5-using-visual-studio-2012-express.aspx